# What is the conditional probability of normal given that another normal is less than a constant

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

Suppose we have a bivariate normal (X, Y), whose mean is zero, and variance 1, and correlation \rho.  Is there an easy formula for 
P(X < x | Y < y ) ?

Comment: You use the definition of conditional probability and will notice that it is just the joint cdf over the marginal cdf.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X,Y}(u,v) dv}{ \int_{-\infty}^{y}f_{Y}(v) dv} du $$

Didn't even require normality.